# Power BI - Retention Policy - basicFIFO

Tags: dataset, powerbi, fifo, policy, retention

Is there a way to get the retention policy applied in a dataset in Power BI?

I have different push datasets in Power BI and some of them include the retention policy basicFIFO (which maintains between 200000 and 210000 rows of only the latest data), however, others don't have it. I can't figure a way to check out which of them have it. If there is any DAX in Power BI or if I can check it in code (which I have tried but didn't make it)

Help?

Comment: Can you please provide your code examples please.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to check the [retention policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/api-automatic-retention-policy-for-real-time-data) of existing dataset.

When you are [creating a dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/pushdatasets/datasets_postdatasetingroup), you specify it with `?defaultRetentionPolicy={defaultRetentionPolicy}` parameter in your request, then it is returned in the json response, but that's all. You are responsible to keep this information in your records. When you try to [get information about a dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/getdatasetingroup) you can see only is it API enabled (`addRowsAPIEnabled`) or not (`Push` or `Hybrid` label in `API Access` column in Power BI).

```
{
  "id": "cfafbeb1-8037-4d0c-896e-a46fb27ff229",
  "name": "SalesMarketing",
  "addRowsAPIEnabled": false,
  "configuredBy": "john@contoso.com",
  "isRefreshable": true,
  "isEffectiveIdentityRequired": true,
  "isEffectiveIdentityRolesRequired": true,
  "isOnPremGatewayRequired": false
}
```

If you want, you can [post an idea](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas) or vote for existing one.